# Как изменить цвета в OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Слева - исходное изображение. Справа- искаженное по цвету изображение. Как мне сделать по цвету левое как правое изображение? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык

Comment: Слева - исходное изображение. Справа - искаженное по цвету изображение. Как мне сделать по цвету левое как правое изображение?

Comment: пройти циклом по пикселям да поменять цвета. судя по розовому там в rgba поменяли местами g и r (простите без очков сейчас)

Comment: Будет слишком долго, не вариант

Comment: долго это сколько ? секунда ? какое разрешение у картинки ?

Comment: @Интик Циклы - плохо, векторные вычисления - хорошо )

Answer (score 3):

Если формат RGB и поменяны каналы r и g, как Интик сказал, то:

```
temp = npimg[:,:,1].copy() 
npimg[:,:,1] = npimg[:,:,0]
npimg[:,:,0] = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, тут поменяны местами не только r и g каналы. Замена такая: rgb->gbr (проверял в XnView).
В OpenCV проще сделать как-то так:

```
b,g,r=cv2.split(img)
img2=cv2.merge((r,b,g))
```

P.S. В общем случае можно преобразовать в HSV ,  циклически сдвинуть канал H и преобразовать обратно.